# Import a database into an empty database project programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, database-project

I wanted to create an extension from Visual Studio that creates a database project of a database (SQL Server) programmatically.

I've created an empty database project in Visual Studio 2017 using C#. Now I wanted to import a database from SQL Server into the database project programmatically (using C#).

When we import a database into a DB project in visual studio, a script of all objects in the database will be created. I wanted to know if there is some way to do the same programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server database.

Comment: Do you really need to do this in code? i mean whats the use case here, as there are far better ways to replicate a database

Comment: Yes. Because I wanted to create an extension to Visual Studio, I will have to programmatically import the database into the DB Project